# Confidence Interval HELP!! Error of estimation to be 3000?

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, confidence-interval

So I am working on a specific stats question. There is a part a and b to it.

**A random sample of professional wrestlers was obtained, and the annual
salary(in dollars) for each was recorded. The summary statistics were x =
47, 500 and n = 18. Assume the distribution of annual salary is normal with
σ = 8, 500.**

**a. Find a 90% confidence interval for the true mean annual salary for all
professional wrestlers.**

**b. How large a sample is necessary in order for the bound on the error of estimation to be 3000?**

Now with Part a) I used the Confidence Formula to find the 90% Interval. It turned to be (44204.29314, 50795.70686).

But I am stuck on Part b) When they "**Error of Estimation to be 3000** now does that mean that I subtract 3000 from the **original** x (mean) of 47,500. Or It it telling me to do something else? Can someone please hep me figure out this part.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you know, a 90% confidence interval is of the form

$$\bar X \pm 1.645\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}.$$

The margin of error is $M = 1.645\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}.$
For (b) set $M = 3000$ and solve for $n.$